# How to set NSDate for UILocalNotifiication

Tags: swift, nsdate, uilocalnotification

My Event Date is output correctly, I have no errors in my page but my app crashes, please help?

I believe it may have something to do with converting my NSString date to NSDate

```
NSLog("This is the EventDate: \(eventdate)")
    let date = eventdate as? NSString



    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    var DateInFormat = dateFormatter.stringFromDate((date as? NSDate)!)

    var notification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.alertBody = "\(eventtitle) is about to start at the \(rsPubName)"
    notification.category = "FIRST_CATEGORY"
    notification.alertAction = "heyaaa"
    notification.fireDate = date as? NSDate!


    NSLog("This is the date: \(date)")
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
```

Comment: There's a lot of weird optional things going on. For example, `(date as? NSDate)!` is very interesting. Why not use `date as! NSDate`? Also, strings CANNOT simply be casted to dates. They have to go through the `dateFromString:` method of `NSDateFormatter`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of mistakes.

Firstly, you cannot simply convert `NSString` to `NSDate` or vice-versa using simple casting. You need to use functions provided by `NSDateFormatter()` like `dateFromString()` or `stringFromDate()`.

Secondly, why are you doing this when you are not using `DateInFormat` in your code anywhere?

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
var DateInFormat = dateFormatter.stringFromDate((date as? NSDate)!)
```

Thirdly, try using something like this to set the date:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
            let calendarComponents = NSDateComponents()
            calendarComponents.hour = 8
            calendarComponents.second = 0
            calendarComponents.minute = 0
            calendarComponents.day = 1
            calendarComponents.year = 2015
            calendarComponents.month = 2
            let dateToFire = calendar.dateFromComponents(calendarComponents)
```

Hope this helps. :)